# Rails 5.1.6 sometimes get ActionController::RoutingError (Resolved)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

My Rails route sometimes get a not found error and resolves itself after a few seconds or sometime need to restart puma to resolves this problem.

```
Started HEAD "/ping" for 127.0.0.1  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/ping"):
actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'

actionpack (5.1.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.6.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.6.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.6.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.6.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
```

```
I, [2023-06-23T12:45:01.491066 #24114]  INFO -- : [ae9a6391-6bc0-47b6-be9c-cbbb42049ae7] Started HEAD "/ping" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-23 12:45:01
I, [2023-06-23T12:45:06.686054 #24114]  INFO -- : [142126c5-6418-4d90-8fff-670d42b3605f] Started HEAD "/ping" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-23 12:45:06
F, [2023-06-23T12:45:06.885745 #24114] FATAL -- : [142126c5-6418-4d90-8fff-670d42b3605f] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/ping"):
```

```
User-MacBook-Pro: User$ rails routes | grep ping
                                                                     ping GET    /ping(.:format)                                                                                 pings#show
```

Does anyone know why it happened and any solution for this?

Comment: This problem has resolved